# Multiplying inputs with dynamic add

Tags: javascript

I have 3 fields with inputs:

```
<div class="row">
<input onblur="calc_basic_amount();" id="rate_basic"></input>
<input onblur="calc_basic_amount();" id="qty_basic"></input>
<input id="basic_amount"></input>
</div>
```

Multiply rate_basic by qty_basic with js:

```
function calc_basic_amount(){
       var qty_basic = document.getElementById('qty_basic').value;
     var rate_basic = document.getElementById('rate_basic').value;
         var basic_amount = (qty_basic * rate_basic);
         document.getElementById('basic_amount').value = basic_amount.toFixed(2);
}
```

It works fine, but I have a button that add a row with the same inputs and the same id, but the calculation only works with the first row. How to make it work with all inputs? thanks

Add function to row:

```
function add_row_to_table() {

        table_row += '<td><input id="qty_basic" type="number" min="0" onblur="calc_basic_amount();" onchange="calc_basic_amount();" data-quantity name="newitems[' + item_key + '][qty]" value="' + data.qty + '" class="form-control">';

        table_row += '<input type="text" placeholder="' + app.lang.unit + '" name="newitems[' + item_key + '][unit]" class="form-control input-transparent text-right" value="' + data.unit + '" >';

        table_row += '</td>';

        table_row += '<td class="rate"><input id="rate_basic" type="number" data-rate data-toggle="tooltip" title="' + app.lang.item_field_not_formatted + '" onblur="calc_basic_amount();" data-rate onchange="calc_basic_amount();" name="newitems[' + item_key + '][rate]" value="' + data.rate + '" class="form-control"></td>';

        table_row += '<td class="amount_basic" align="right"><input id="basic_amount" class="form-control"></td>';

        table_row += '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" onclick="delete_item(this,' + itemid + '); return false;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>';

        table_row += '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: show me function that created new row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add dynamic id

```
<div class="row">
<input onblur="calc_basic_amount(1);" id="rate_basic1"></input>
<input onblur="calc_basic_amount(1);" id="qty_basic1"></input>
<input id="basic_amount1"></input>
</div>
```

Now when you create New Row

```
<div class="row">
<input onblur="calc_basic_amount(2);" id="rate_basic2"></input>
<input onblur="calc_basic_amount(2);" id="qty_basic2"></input>
<input id="basic_amount2"></input>
</div>
```

```
function calc_basic_amount(id){
       var qty_basic = document.getElementById('qty_basic'+id).value;
       var rate_basic = document.getElementById('rate_basic'+id).value;
       var basic_amount = (qty_basic * rate_basic);
       document.getElementById('basic_amount'+id).value = basic_amount.toFixed(2);
}
```

---

https://codepen.io/flakerimi/pen/xxgVpWR
I have simplified a bit but you get the idea.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
function addRow() {
  currentNum = rowCount+1;
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = '<input onblur="calc_basic_amount('+currentNum+');" id="rate_basic'+currentNum+'" />';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<input onblur="calc_basic_amount('+currentNum+');" id="qty_basic'+currentNum+'"/>'; 
  cell3.innerHTML = '<input id="basic_amount'+currentNum+'"/>';
  rowCount++;
}

 function calc_basic_amount(id){
       var qty_basic = document.getElementById('qty_basic'+id).value;
       var rate_basic = document.getElementById('rate_basic'+id).value;
       var basic_amount = (qty_basic * rate_basic);
       document.getElementById('basic_amount'+id).value = basic_amount.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the buttons to create and delete row(s) for the table.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input onblur="calc_basic_amount(1);" id="rate_basic1" /></td>
 <td><input onblur="calc_basic_amount(1);" id="qty_basic1"/></td>
 <td><input id="basic_amount1"/></td>


  </tr>

</table>
<br>

<button onclick="addRow()">Create row</button>

 <script>

</script>
```

Comment: It looks cool, thanks for the attached function to my question which add row to my table. It adds a static id, how to make it dynamic? thank you